# Sum of combinations of the n by consecutive k

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, binomial-coefficients

In a book, I found that the sum of combinations: $\binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k+1} +\cdots+ \binom{n}{n}$, where *k* starts from 0, equals  $2^n$. It is possible to express this statement via sum: $2 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{n!\over k!(n-k)!} = 2^n$, using binomial theorem. I tried several small n values, such as 4, 6 and others, the statement looks correct. But I can't find a regularity, respectively I can't understand, **how to prove the truth of the statement?**

Comment: try $a=1,b=1$ in $(a+b)^n = \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k}$

Comment: An alternate way to do this is to observe that both sides give the number of subsets of a set with n elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k y^{n-k}$$

For $x=1$ and $y=1$:

$$2^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+ \dots +\binom{n}{n-1}+\binom{n}{n}$$