# Alternating sum of combinations of the n by consecutive k

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, combinations

Like in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908131/sum-of-combinations-of-the-n-by-consecutive-k) I have to prove that the alternating sum equals 0. If n is even the case is easy: there exist a bijection between the elements of the series and they cancel each other out. If n is odd than I get an alternating sum of the numbers from a given row in Pascal's trangle... and what now?

Comment: Hint: $\color{red}{(1)}+\color{blue}{(4)}+\color{red}{(6)}+\color{blue}{(4)}+\color{red}{(1)} = \color{red}{(1)}+\color{blue}{(1+3)} +\color{red}{(3+3)}+\color{blue}{(3+1)}+\color{red}{(1)}$ (The second 1 should be red, but for some reason it doesn’t render properly.)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, nevermind. The answer is at:
https://www.math.hmc.edu/~benjamin/papers/DIE.pdf

Comment: An easier method for this particular case (but not as general): expand $(1+(−1))^n$.